# Right way to check if a third party site has been banned by Google?

Tags: google

Is there a proper/reliable test to find out whether a third party site has been banned by Google?

An old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214571/seo-how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-website-has-been-banned-by-google) mentions using:

```
site:PLACE_URL_HERE
```

Is this a reliable option?

Someone has mentioned the [Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3), but it does not seem to cover for banned sites.

Ideally, I would like to implement some Javascript code taking in a url and returning true/false if the site has been banned or not.

Comment: Short of what you have already mentioned and what is given in Google Webmaster Tools, Google does not give any clues for a site penalty. This is intentional. Doing a site: search for a site that has performed well for a solid period of time and finding nothing is a good clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using site:domain.com will see if its been completely de-indexed, but that's pretty harsh on the scale of penalties Google can dish out.  Others you may want to try are:

- Seeing if they rank for their brand term.  If its uncompetitive and they are not #1, this can be a sign they have had a penalty
- Check the PageRank to see if its 0, although unreliable these days as its updated not very often.  But if they have lots of backlinks, and 0 PageRank thats a pretty good signal to see they have been penalised for selling links.
- SearchMetrics has general website traffic monitoring, which has shown in the past decreases for websites in rankings